# Ruby On Rails and redmine Aglie plugin fixing

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Well, as maybe you know guys, in redmine base sturcture there are tables `issues`, `projects`. I never used to write code in ruby before btw. But I got task, so.
Here the `issues` table structure:
[image]
And here is the `project` table structure:
[image] 
The problem is I need to get all `issues` where `project_id equals @project and project.parent_id equals @project` too. 
The problem is, first I don't understand what current @project contents. Second I got no idea how to access to the @project's parent_id field here. `Parent_id` is referenced to the project.id field by the way.

I got ruby function here.
Boss said I need to edit scope variable. So I trying to edit it like this:

```
def find_no_version_issues
    @backlog_version = @project.versions.open.where("LOWER(#{Version.table_name}.name) LIKE LOWER(?)", "backlog").first ||
        @project.versions.open.where(:effective_date => nil).first ||
        Version.open.where(:project_id => @project).order("effective_date ASC").first

         @current_version = Version.open.
        where(:project_id => @project).
        where("#{Version.table_name}.id <> ?", @backlog_version).
        order("effective_date DEcSC").first

    q = (params[:q] || params[:term]).to_s.strip
    #scope = (params[:scope] == "all" || @project.nil? ? Issue : @project.issues).open.visible.where(:fixed_version_id => nil).sorted_by_rank
    scope = Issue.open.visible.where(:fixed_version_id => nil).where("project_id = ?", ) OR @project.or(:project_id.parent_id => @project)).sorted_by_rank
    #scope = Issue.open.visible.where(:project_id => @current_version) #(:project_id => @project || @project.parent_id == :project_id || @project ).sorted_by_rank
    if q.present?
      if q.match(/^#?(\d+)\z/)
        scope = scope.where("(#{Issue.table_name}.id = ?) OR (LOWER(#{Issue.table_name}.subject) LIKE LOWER(?))", $1.to_i, "%#{q}%")
      else
        scope = scope.where("LOWER(#{Issue.table_name}.subject) LIKE LOWER(?)", "%#{q}%")
      end
    end
    @issue_count = scope.count
    @issue_pages = Redmine::Pagination::Paginator.new @issue_count, 20, params['page']
    @version_issues = scope.offset(@issue_pages.offset).limit(@issue_pages.per_page).all
  end
```

So, please, could somebody help me? How could I understand, what @project contains? How could I turn query into scope?

Here's working SQL-query (or at least it got rows I need). But I really have no idea how to make this `scope` varible contains this data?

```
SELECT * FROM `issues` WHERE `project_id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `projects` WHERE `parent_id` IS NOT NULL OR `parent_id` IS NULL ) ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually I fixed this thing this way

```
 def find_no_version_issues
    q = (params[:q] || params[:term]).to_s.strip
    #scope = (params[:scope] == "all" || @project.nil? ? Issue : @project.issues).open.visible.where(:fixed_version_id => nil).sorted_by_rank
    @subprojects = @project.descendants.visible.all
    @subprojects = @subprojects.to_a.push @project
    scope = Issue.open.visible.where(project_id:@subprojects).where(:fixed_version_id => nil).sorted_by_rank
    if q.present?
      if q.match(/^#?(\d+)\z/)
        scope = scope.where("(#{Issue.table_name}.id = ?) OR (LOWER(#{Issue.table_name}.subject) LIKE LOWER(?))", $1.to_i, "%#{q}%")
      else
        scope = scope.where("LOWER(#{Issue.table_name}.subject) LIKE LOWER(?)", "%#{q}%")
      end
    end
    @issue_count = scope.count
    @issue_pages = Redmine::Pagination::Paginator.new @issue_count, 20, params['page']
    @version_issues = scope.offset(@issue_pages.offset).limit(@issue_pages.per_page).all
  end
```